# what are the angles , and ϕ values of the following quantum state?

Tags: quantum-state, nielsen-and-chuang, bloch-sphere

I need to find the coordinate  and ϕ values of the quantum state on the bloch sphere
$$
\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \left| 0 \right> + {\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}} \left| 1\right>
$$

Comment: Haven't you asked literally the same question before, just with different coefficients?

Answer (score 2):

You have normalized state
$$|\psi\rangle=\alpha|0\rangle + \beta|1\rangle$$

First, write the state as
$$|\psi\rangle=\frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|}\left({|\alpha|}|0\rangle + \frac{\beta|\alpha|}{\alpha}|1\rangle\right)$$

The factor $$\frac{\alpha}{|\alpha|}$$ is a global phase and not important. Now you have
$$\cos{\frac{\theta}{2}}=|\alpha|$$
which gives the value of $\theta$ and
$$\sin{\frac{\theta}{2}}e^{i\phi}=\frac{\beta|\alpha|}{\alpha}$$
which gives the value of $\phi$

Comment: @Alexey Krugovets

Comment: Okay great job but I have trouble to solve this state. @kludg