# Simplify the system to find the $\theta$, $\phi$ on bloch sphere

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, bloch-sphere

I have problem to simplify the quantum system states on bloch sphere to get $\theta$, $\phi$ values,
My question is not duplicated!
$$
\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{3}} \left| 0 \right> + {\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}} \left| 1\right>
$$

Comment: Same question asked here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9410/what-are-the-angles-and-%cf%95-values-of-the-following-quantum-state

Comment: No,in this link question is not answer yet..

Comment: The link in my second comment deals with the same quantum state and below it is general description how to solve such problems. Which particular part of the solving you need to help with?

Comment: If you think you can solve it, submit your solution of this quantum state, and do not give a suggestion to the website that the question is duplicated, please! @MartinVesely

Comment: See here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9466/coordinates-theta-and-phi-on-bloch-sphere/9467#9467 Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much mr. @MartinVesely