# Finding the polar and azimuthal angles of the Bloch vector corresponding to $\frac1{\sqrt2}(1-i)|0\rangle-\frac i{\sqrt2}|1\rangle$

Tags: quantum-state, bloch-sphere

I need to find the polar angles and azimuthal angles of the following bloch vector:

$$
\frac{1-i}{2}|0\rangle - \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle
$$

I just couldn't figure it out, and I could also not find out how I could factor out the global phase, can anyone here please help?

I got to the point where I knew that $\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) = \frac{1-i}{2}$ and $\sin (\frac{\theta}{2}) e^{i\phi} = -\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$, I'm guessing I have to factor out some global phase here and ignore it in order to solve the equations, but I couldn't figure it out. I've tried looking elsewhere for methods on how to solve this, but could not find it.

Comment: I've edited my post with what I figured out so far. For $|0\rangle$ I'd say polar angle is 0 and for $|1\rangle$ it is $\pi$?

Comment: does https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9404/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/10122/55, or one of the links therein, answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing your amplitudes in polar form
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-i\pi/4}|0\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-i\pi/2}|1\rangle.
$$
This makes it easy to pull out the global phase, as you suggest. What should you pick? The one that makes the amplitude in front of $|0\rangle$ real. In other words,
$$
e^{-i\pi/4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle+\frac{e^{-i\pi/4}}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle\right).
$$
Now you can set
$$
\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
and
$$
\sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-i\pi/4}.
$$
In other words, $\theta=\pi/2$ and $\phi=-\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you were able to compute the $x, y, z$ coordinates of the state on the Bloch sphere (where $r = 1$), then there is the standard conversion of cartesian coordinates $(x, y, z)$ to spherical coordinates $(r, \theta, \phi)$:
$$
  \cos \theta = \frac{z}{r}
$$
$$
  \cos \phi = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$

To compute the cartesian coordinates $x, y, z$ for a state $\psi$ you first make a density matrix by computing the outer product of the state with itself:
$$
\rho = |\psi\rangle\langle\psi|
$$
and then compute something equivalent to [this](https://github.com/qcc4cp/qcc/blob/7d1a0f9075fde9fd0f443fab716786d145926cd5/src/lib/helper.py#L40) code:

```
def density_to_cartesian(rho: np.ndarray) -> Tuple[float, float, float]:
  """Compute Bloch sphere coordinates from 2x2 density matrix."""

  a = rho[0, 0]
  b = rho[1, 0]
  x = 2.0 * b.real
  y = 2.0 * b.imag
  z = 2.0 * a - 1.0
```